# How To Add ':' Character Near My Label With Many Space Character

Tags: html, css, special-characters, padding, spaces

I want to create form like as below:

```
abc         :
abcdefg     :
```

'abc' has 3 character. 'abc      :' is 20 character. So space should have 17 character.
'abcdefg' has 7 character. 'abcdefg    :' is 20 character. So space should have 13 character. I don't want to add space with  &nbsp character.

```
 <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">abc<span style="padding-left:17px;">:</span></label>

<label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">abcdefg<span style="padding-left:13px;">:</span></label>
```

Above code is not true  because 'px' is not equal to one character space.

I don't want to write code like as below:

```
 <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">abc &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp...:</label>
```

How can i add more than one character space with padding style ? For example can i  write js function to add more than one space character with $nbsp ? Like as below:

```
function AddMultiCharacterSpace(charCount){ ... }
```

Comment: Are you using a monospace font? If not, the variance between letter width will be all over the place depending on the letter - so there is no single "character width" - it would depend on the letter. Alternatively, you can use `em` or `rem`

Comment: Something like: `.col-form-label { width: 100px; } .col-form-label:after { content: ':'; float: right; }` and a simple `<label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">abc</span>`. Where the width of `100px` is just an assumption, of course this can be anything in `%|vw` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can give your label a width you can try using a pseudo-element:

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}
label::after {
  content: ':';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<label>abc</label>

<label>abcdefg</label>
```

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/mRPPdx)**

Answer (score 0):

```css
label {
 width: 100px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">
 <span>abc</span>
 <span>:</span>
</label>
<label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">
 <span>abcdefg</span>
 <span>:</span>
</label>
```

p.s. just pick desired width for label.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this.

For your `label` element, set `display: inline-block` (for example, `block` may also be an option).

You also need to specify a width value.

To place the `:` character, you can use the `:after` pseudo element and float it to the right.

```css
label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
label:after {
  content: ':';
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<label>abc</label><br>
<label>abcdfgh</label>
```

Comment: I prefer this solution to mine.

Comment: Our solutions are similar.  I find it hard to think of a situation that would give preference to one or the other.